# general question about polars memory management

Tags: python-polars

I have some general questions about memory management in Polars. It would be great if you can spend a few sentences on how it works, like when is memory allocated and when it's reclaimed.

In particular I would like to know how to delete some memory from a dataframe. I want to do it in a way that is immediate and doesn't go through the Python garbage collection mechanism if possible. It's not too bad if I have to call gc.collect() immediately after but that's not preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, but I'll have a go at it.

In `python-polars`, a `Series` or a `DataFrame`'s deletion is determined by pythons reference counting garbage collection just like any other python object.

Next there is the fact that polars memory is also reference counted. So if we create a new `DataFrame` that copies data from an already existing `DataFrame/Series` that data is not copied, but a reference count is incremented.

So for instance in the example below we have 2 DataFrames totalling 4 columns, but we only have 3 columns in memory because the column `"a"` is shared between both `DataFrame`s. And will only get deleted if the reference count is 0.

The same principle also counts for slicing `Series`. A slice never copies data, but merely increments a reference count and updates an `offset` and `length` field.

```py
df_a = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": ["a", "b", "c"]
})

df_b = df_a.select(["a", pl.col("b") + "py"])

print(df_a)
print(df_b)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ a   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ b   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ c   │
└─────┴─────┘
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ apy │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ bpy │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ cpy │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: What happens when I do this? a = a[:50]. (get first 50 rows of a). Let's assume there are no other references of a. Will the rest of a be deleted from memory?

Comment: No, you still hold a slice into that buffer.

Comment: Is there a way of writing code to make sure that the original buffer gets deleted then?

Comment: Copy data into a new buffer: `pl.Series(pl.Series([1, 2, 3])[1:].to_numpy())`. 

Or use an operation that creates a new buffer, such as a filter. But I would not worry too much about this. If there is another reference count to the buffer, it will not get deleted.

The memory buffer could be part of another `Series` or `DataFrame`. Could you elaborate more on what the issue behind the question is?

Comment: polars.concat does not copy data right?

Comment: I guess another question is is there a more efficient way of merging two sorted polars dataframes other than polars.concat([df1,df2]).sort(key)?

Comment: > polars.concat does not copy data right? 

Only if `rechunk=True`

Comment: Will rechunk= True lead to any performance improvement? What's the reason behind it? @ritchie46